# WCF RESTful Post with Stream return

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, https

I have WCF Web service using https. It has next interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
class Service
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate="Method", BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    byte[] Method(Stream request)
    {
        // ... Some logic ...
        return someBytes;
    }
}
```

This works good but has one little issue. After method completition it closes up https connection. I have another method in service with WebGet. It returns Stream object, and this one doesn't close https connection.
I've tried to use same approach in my first Method and rewrited it as follows:

```
[ServiceContract]
class Service
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate="Method", BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    Stream Method(Stream request)
    {
        // ... Some logic ...
        return new MemoryStream(someBytes);
    }
}
```

But when I'm trying to consume Method with a client the service responds: "Method not allowed. Allowed: GET, HEAD".
Please tell me if I'm doiing it wrong by returning Stream object, or I have missed something.

UPD:
I also appreciate in any hints about tracing down this problem.

Comment: Returning a Stream object from a WCF REST service should work just fine.  I also don't know why returning byte[] would close the connection.  Closing the connection happens on the client.  What are you using as a client library?

Comment: UrlOpenBlockingStreamW. But this is not that closes connection. Because using this for GET methods works fine and doesn't closes connection at all.

Comment: If the server returns the HTTP Header `Connection: close` then the client closes the connection.  You could use Fiddler to see what is going on.

Comment: Fiddler shows that I've already mentioned. In case WebGet(Stream return) - Connection: Keep-Alive. In case WebInvoke(byte[]) - Connection: Close. I hope this relies on return type. If POST method is the reason to close connection, then there is nothing to do. I want to figure this out.